# Removing the horizontal rule from markdown headings in vs code

Tags: markdown, underline, heading

I cannot figure out how to remove the horizontal rule that is automatically appended after each heading when using markdown in vs code.

How do I remove the horizontal rule so I can have just plain text headings without the added horizontal rule underneath the text? I'm a technical writer exploring markdown in vs code and have some familiarity with .css style sheets, but am still a novice as I don't use style sheets regularly.

I haven't found anything in settings. I also tried using my own custom .css style sheet with some of the following combinations, but nothing worked:

```
hr {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0%;
}

h1+hr {
    border: 0px;
}
```